# WP REST API v2 JSON endpoints appear difficult to read

Tags: json, wordpress, rest, api

I found WP REST API very interesting in making custom functionalities in WordPress websites. However, I find it hard to read my JSON endpoints' results.

The normal output of JSON endpoint is wrapped in `html` and `pre` tags. T result appears in one long line of compressed string.

[image]

I need to integrate my [website](https://store.alwasail.com) to a mobile app to be done by another developer and I would like to display the API endpoints (e.g. [link](https://store.alwasail.com/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/35)) to appear as a regular JSON Object like:

[image]

I'm trying to find a workaround like [a hook or a filter](https://v2.wp-api.org/extending/hooks/) to make the JSON results appear as I desired. Or equivalent AJAX related code would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use a Chrome extension of JSON Formatter to view the results which prints out with readability in mind.
https://github.com/callumlocke/json-formatter